# Problema com condição IN no sub-select

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Estou com o seguinte problema;

Estou tentando fazer uma pesquisa e incluir o valor do `WHERE` principal em um *sub-select*, porém o resultado sempre é informado como 0, sendo que há registros.

Parte da `query` que estou com dificuldades é esta:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Colaboradores' FROM SRA010 WHERE RA_FILIAL = sd3.D3_FILIAL
 AND (RA_SITFOLH NOT IN ('D', 'A') OR RA_DEMISSA  > CAST(YEAR(sd3.D3_EMISSAO) AS VARCHAR)+CAST(REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO))) + RTrim(MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO)) AS VARCHAR)+'31')
 AND RA_CC IN (SELECT CTT_CUSTO FROM CTT010 WHERE sd3.D3_CC = CTT_CUSTO)) as Pessoas
FROM SD3010 AS sd3
WHERE sd3.D3_TM = '010'
AND sd3.D3_LOCAL IN ('01','02')
AND sd3.D3_FILIAL = '0301'
AND sd3.D3_CC in ('1350400', '1350403', '1350405', '1350408', '1350409', '1350410', '1350411', '1350412', '1350413', '1350414', '1350415', '1350416', '1350417', '1350418', '1350419', '1350420', '1350421', '1350422', '1350423', '1350424', '1350425', '1350426', '1350427', '1350428', '1350429', '1350430', '1350431', '1350432', '13604', '1360400', '1360401', '1360402', '1360499')
AND sd3.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'  
AND sd3.D3_EMISSAO between '20161001' and '20161031'
group by sd3.D3_EMISSAO, sd3.D3_TM, sd3.D3_FILIAL, sd3.D3_CC
```

Preciso que a condição do *sd3.D3_CC* no fim da *query*, no *WHERE*, vá para o *WHERE* no sd3.CC no subselect

Obs: Há mais `subselects` que não interferem neste informado, porém, informei apenas este para que possa ficar mais clara a compreensão.

Obs2: Outras condições no `Where` principal, como o campo  *sd3.D3_FILIAL (na 1ª condição do subselect)*, funcionam corretamente.

Obs3: Essa query vai se transformar em uma view, q servirá como análise do BI, podendo ser alterada a opção sd3.D3_CC no filtro, ou seja, os valores do campo sd3.D3_CC não são fixos, estão na query apenas para simular os filtros do BI

Atualização: Retirando a condição *AND RA_CC IN (SELECT CTT_CUSTO FROM CTT010 WHERE sd3.D3_CC = CTT_CUSTO)* no subselect, ele exibe resultados, conforme imagem abaixo (1º Result com a condição citada acima, 2º Result sem a condição citada acima)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sem a estrutura da tabela e alguns dados para testarmos fica muito dificil. Adicione isso a pergunta.

Comment: Se você tiver uma consulta que retorna os valores que estão no in, dá pra usar como sub-consulta no WHERE da consulta externa e interna. Do contrário, vais ter que repetir o in nos dois locais.

Comment: Outra coisa: Não utilizar a cláusula **"IN"** por questão de performance. Busque sempre utilizar a cláusula **NOT EXISTS** OU **EXISTS**.

Comment: @CristianoBombazar, no caso acima o IN é mais indicado, ele tem uma lista e não um select de outra tabela.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Acabei não terminando meu comentário. Falei do EXISTS, caso os valores possam ser obtidos por sub-consulta. Desculpe.

Comment: @CristianoBombazar, sem problema.

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro, a construção 
"RA_CC IN (SELECT CTT_CUSTO FROM CTT010 WHERE sd3.D3_CC = CTT_CUSTO))"
me pareceu estranha. Neste caso, o IN está com a função de EXISTS?

Comment: @JoséDiz Está apenas o IN...a ideia seria ele buscar o RA_CC dentro deste conjunto de dados trazidos pelo SELECT CTT_CUSTO FROM........

Answer (score 3):

Se é que entendi direito, o seu SubSelect esta fazendo um `RA_CC IN (sd3.D3_CC))`, isso vair ser verificado UM a UM para cada valor da sua consulta externar, ou seja para cada linha que o seu `select` fizer ele vai verificar o valor do campo `D3_CC` que certamente será um unico valor e não uma lista.

Altere sua consulta para;

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Colaboradores' FROM SRA010 WHERE RA_FILIAL = sd3.D3_FILIAL
     AND (RA_SITFOLH NOT IN ('D', 'A') OR RA_DEMISSA  > CAST(YEAR(sd3.D3_EMISSAO) AS VARCHAR)+CAST(REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO))) + RTrim(MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO)) AS VARCHAR)+'31')
     AND RA_CC IN ('1350400', '1350403', '1350405', '1350408', '1350409', '1350410', '1350411', '1350412', '1350413', '1350414', '1350415', '1350416', '1350417', '1350418', '1350419', '1350420', '1350421', '1350422', '1350423', '1350424', '1350425', '1350426', '1350427', '1350428', '1350429', '1350430', '1350431', '1350432', '13604', '1360400', '1360401', '1360402', '1360499')) as Pessoas
FROM SD3010 AS sd3

WHERE sd3.D3_TM = '010'
AND sd3.D3_LOCAL IN ('01','02')
AND sd3.D3_FILIAL = '0301'
AND sd3.D3_CC in ('1350400', '1350403', '1350405', '1350408', '1350409', '1350410', '1350411', '1350412', '1350413', '1350414', '1350415', '1350416', '1350417', '1350418', '1350419', '1350420', '1350421', '1350422', '1350423', '1350424', '1350425', '1350426', '1350427', '1350428', '1350429', '1350430', '1350431', '1350432', '13604', '1360400', '1360401', '1360402', '1360499')
AND sd3.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'  


AND sd3.D3_EMISSAO between '20161001' and '20161031'

group by sd3.D3_EMISSAO, sd3.D3_TM, sd3.D3_FILIAL, sd3.D3_CC
```

Comment: Assim funciona, mas estes valores do sd3.D3_CC não são fixos. Coloquei os mesmos apenas para simular resultados. Eles serão alterados, conforme condição informada. Por isso que precisaria passar os valores do IN (no where principal) para o subselect. E pode ser mais de um valor a ser enviado para o subselect, por isso o IN

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro Qual consulta você utiliza para retornar esses valores do sd3.D3_CC?

Comment: @CristianoBombazar Está vindo de um INNER JOIN...INNER JOIN CTT010 AS ctt ON (sd3_sub1.D3_CC = ctt.CTT_CUSTO)

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro, no caso você tem que fazer um select dentro do seu IN(select campo tabela where sd3_sub1.D3_CC = ctt.CTT_CUSTO), algo assim

Comment: @CristianoBombazar No IN do subselect? ou do where principal?

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro O do where...

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro, qual seu banco de dados? você conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: @CristianoBombazar uso o SQL Server...tentei como você sugeriu, porém continua retornando a contagem como 0. Se uso um valor em específico da condição no IN (valor '1360401', por exemplo), colocando como valor fixo, ele retorna a quantidade de registros certa.
Última alteração na query que fiz foi nesta parte:

AND RA_CC IN (SELECT CTT_CUSTO FROM CTT010 WHERE sd3.D3_CC = CTT_CUSTO)) as Pessoas

se alterar para 
AND RA_CC IN ('1360401')) as Pessoas
ele traz corretamente

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro Posta o SQL atualizado. Edita sua pergunta...

Comment: @CristianoBombazar Atualizado

Answer (score 2):

Abaixo, atualizei somente a parte externa do seu SQL com duas maneiras de se fazer. De qualquer forma, a qual você escolher, você copia e usa também no IN da consulta interna.

```
SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Colaboradores' 
           FROM SRA010 
          WHERE RA_FILIAL = sd3.D3_FILIAL
            AND (RA_SITFOLH NOT IN ('D', 'A') OR RA_DEMISSA  > CAST(YEAR(sd3.D3_EMISSAO) AS VARCHAR)+CAST(REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO))) + RTrim(MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO)) AS VARCHAR)+'31')
            AND RA_CC IN ('1350400', '1350403', '1350405', '1350408', '1350409', '1350410', '1350411', '1350412', '1350413', '1350414', '1350415', '1350416', '1350417', '1350418', '1350419', '1350420', '1350421', '1350422', '1350423', '1350424', '1350425', '1350426', '1350427', '1350428', '1350429', '1350430', '1350431', '1350432', '13604', '1360400', '1360401', '1360402', '1360499')) as Pessoas
 FROM SD3010 AS sd3
WHERE sd3.D3_TM = '010'
  AND sd3.D3_LOCAL IN ('01','02')
  AND sd3.D3_FILIAL = '0301'
  --AND sd3.D3_CC in ('1350400', '1350403', '1350405', '1350408', '1350409', '1350410', '1350411', '1350412', '1350413', '1350414', '1350415', '1350416', '1350417', '1350418', '1350419', '1350420', '1350421', '1350422', '1350423', '1350424', '1350425', '1350426', '1350427', '1350428', '1350429', '1350430', '1350431', '1350432', '13604', '1360400', '1360401', '1360402', '1360499')
  **--UTILIZANDO IN (NÃO RECOMENDADO)**
  AND sd3.D3_CC in (SELECT D3_CC 
                      FROM tabela1
                      JOIN tabela2 ON(tabela1.id = tabela2.id)
                     WHERE --informar clausulas aqui, onde vai retornar sua lista de D3_CC
           )
**--UTILIZANDO EXISTS  (RECOMENDADO POR QUESTÃO DE PERFORMANCE)

**  AND EXISTS (SELECT TRUE 
                      FROM tabela1
                      JOIN tabela2 ON(tabela1.id = tabela2.id)
                     WHERE sd3.D3_CC = tabela1.D3_CC --informar outras clausulas aqui, onde vai retornar sua lista D3_cc
                     )

  AND sd3.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'

  AND sd3.D3_EMISSAO between '20161001' and '20161031'
GROUP BY sd3.D3_EMISSAO, sd3.D3_TM, sd3.D3_FILIAL, sd3.D3_CC
```

Acredito que exista uma forma melhor de se fazer, mas como não tenho nenhum dado para testar a consulta, pode ser que ele tenha ficado errada. De qualquer forma, vou postar abaixo, e você modifica para o seu caso.

```
SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Colaboradores' 
           FROM SRA010 
          WHERE RA_FILIAL = sd3.D3_FILIAL
            AND (RA_SITFOLH NOT IN ('D', 'A') OR RA_DEMISSA  > CAST(YEAR(sd3.D3_EMISSAO) AS VARCHAR)+CAST(REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO))) + RTrim(MONTH(sd3.D3_EMISSAO)) AS VARCHAR)+'31')
            AND RA_CC = foo.D3_CC) as Pessoas
 FROM SD3010 AS sd3
 JOIN (SELECT D3_CC 
                      FROM tabela1
                      JOIN tabela2 ON(tabela1.id = tabela2.id)
                     WHERE --informar clausulas aqui, onde vai retornar sua lista de D3_CC
                     ) AS foo ON (foo.D3_CC = sd3.d3_cc)
WHERE sd3.D3_TM = '010'
  AND sd3.D3_LOCAL IN ('01','02')
  AND sd3.D3_FILIAL = '0301'

  AND sd3.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'

  AND sd3.D3_EMISSAO between '20161001' and '20161031'
GROUP BY sd3.D3_EMISSAO, sd3.D3_TM, sd3.D3_FILIAL, sd3.D3_CC
```

Qualquer dúvida, estou a disposição.

Comment: Entendi sua lógica...porém não daria para eu colocar a condição lá em cima pq a query vai se transformar em uma view, q servirá como análise do BI, podendo ser alterada a opção sd3.D3_CC no filtro

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro O terceiro exemplo é justamente isso. Não tais colocando a condição em cima. Somente ligando os resultados da tabela apelidada como "foo", que é somente os sd3.D3_CC.

Comment: Esta "tabela2", seria a tabela que retornaria os valores da sd3.D3_CC?

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro Aquele SQL ali dentro é só um exemplo de como você pode fazer. O importante é que dentro daquela consulta ali, é que retorne os valores de  **sd3.D3_CC**. Apenas isso.

Comment: Continua trazendo valor 0. Conferi no select do Join que você sugeriu como exemplo, e está trazendo os registros corretamente do sd3.D3_CC. Fiz algo errado? Segue query http://pastebin.com/3aD1GVFJ

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro Remove o **sd3.D3_CC in (...)** da consulta externa. E na consulta interna, ali em `AND RA_CC = foo.D3_CC` , esse relacionamento realmente está correto?

Comment: Nesta base de dados, há 2 tabelas com estas informações. Alterei a tabela no JOIN, por precaução, porém, continua com o mesmo resultado. o relacionamento está correto, pois são duas chaves. segue query com a alteração para a outra tabela e sem a condição sd3.D3_CC: http://pastebin.com/edxsBEtY